# Batch Check/Get variable in URL

Tags: batch-file

I try check or get data in ulr, but, not working.

He does not do the online check/get.

```
set fileon=http://example.com/file.txt
findstr /l "teste@test.com" %fileon%
if %errorlevel%==0 (echo This ok) else (echo Not ok)
```

Please, help-me.

Comment: That won't work. You need to download the file first and then check it on a local resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file with [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/):

```
set _outFile=outfile.txt
set _url=http://example.com/file.txt
curl -o %_outFile% %_url%
```

Then do your thing on %_outFile%.

If you have git for windows, try `where curl`, you might already have it on your system.